# Plotting curves with Paraview

Tags: plot, paraview

I'm using Paraview in order to plot some numerical results, which are saved in format .vtu after the execution of my code.

When I try to plot a 1D curve, like a simple function Y=f(X), I obtain only the line of the domain colored in function of the values of Y. The same clearly happens when I plot a 2D surface: I get the domain colored according to the values of f(X,Y).

My question is: there is a way to plot the profile of Y (and f(X,Y) in the bi-dimensional case) like we do when using 'plot' and 'surf' Matlab?

I've already read the manual of Paraview but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but try the Warp By Scalar filter in ParaView.